# Size of arrays in MemoryLayout.size in Swift

Tags: arrays, swift, unsafe, memory-layout

Sorry if the question may be duplicate I neither could find it here nor using Google.

I'm new to unsafe Swift and I was wondering why the size of an array of Bools which is e.g 10 bytes, is still 8 bytes ?

If I wasn't able to say what I meant I would be wondering if you could take a look at this code :

```
var boolArray = [Bool]()
for _ in 1...10{
    boolArray.append(true)
}
print(MemoryLayout.size(ofValue: boolArray))
```

I don't get why it prints 8 while the array has 10 bools which at least contains of 10 bytes.

Comment: You need only 2 bytes to store 16 bits. 1 byte is equal to 8bits

Comment: Unrelated but useful: you can shorten that array generation to `Array(repeating: true, count: 10)` Or if you're dealing with classes and want 10 distinct objects: `(1...10).map { _ in YourClass() }`

Comment: @LeoDabus `Array<Bool>` doesn't (currently) do any bit packing. It uses 1 byte `Bool`s.

Comment: I didn’t say so. Just his wording it is not correct.

Comment: @LeoDabus Does that comma I added in this edit solve your problem ?

Comment: I don’t have any problem. I just said that you don’t need at least 10 bytes

Comment: @Alexander-ReinstateMonica Thank for you for reminding me I just forgot it

Comment: @LeoDabus You're the best kind of right - _technically right_

Comment: @LeoDabus If I'm wrong please correct me. The smallest addressable unit in computers is 1 byte therefore even bytes need at least 1 bytes to be stored and an array of 10 bools need 10 bytes not 10 bits.

Comment: @ParsaNoori Technically, you can't even load anything less than a cache line on modern CPUs. But you can still access the constituents. While you can't load a single bit by itself, you can load an entire byte, mask away all bits except for the one you're looking for, and read it.

Comment: @ParsaNoori Since there are 8 bits per byte, you can use all but the last 3 bits of the index to pick which byte to look at, and use the last 3 bits to encode the location of the bit you're interested int.  For example, if you want the `Bool` at index 59 (`0b111011` in binary), you look at the 7th byte (`0b111`). Lets say the value of that byte was `0b11111111` (all "true"). We care about bit 3 ( `0b011`), so we mask `0b1111111` by ANDing it with the mask `0b00000100`. The result is `0b00000100`, which means the 3rd bit was set.

Comment: @ParsaNoori If instead the byte had a value of `0b11111011`, after masking it with `0b00000100`, we would get `0x00000000`, meaning the 3rd bit was off.

Comment: @Alexander-ReinstateMonica Accepted completely but since the compiler doesn't work that way, Is it worth implementing these low level works instead of easily using implemented booleans in the language itself while modern memories contain way more than the amount of these words ?

Comment: @ParsaNoori Firstly, the compiler *can* pack bit patterns, and it does so all the time. [For example `Optional<Bool>` is just 1 byte. It encodes `false` as `0b00`, `true` as `0b01` and `nil` as `0b10`.](https://gist.github.com/amomchilov/30e7a402f53d8840e484a4feed281193). It just happens to not do it for `Array<Bool>`. Furthermore, bit fields are still hugely relevant, even with modern memory amounts. [For example, they're used ubiquitously in game engines for define which layers can physically interact with which other layers.](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/LayerBasedCollision.html)

Comment: @Alexander-ReinstateMonica Thank you so much, helped me a lot

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because the result of function size does not include any dynamically allocated or out of line storage. See [`MemoryLayout.size(ofValue:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/memorylayout/2486283-size)

Answer (score 5):

That's because an `Array` itself don't really store anything - internally, they hold a reference to heap-allocated piece of memory, which really stores the data.

One of the reasons it's done this way is optimization - it allows the use of copy-on-write mechanism. `Array` is a `struct`, therefore it's a value type. However, the data it holds does not need to be copied every time you copy the `Array` - instead, multiple `Arrays` can point to the same area of memory, as long as they do not modify it.

Comment: It's reasonable to guess that the data-structure which represents "the `Array` *container*" is 8 bytes long.  This is an opaque structure that is of interest only to the language designers.

Comment: @MikeRobinson To the contrary, it's inner working is fascinating, and could be of great interest of many who've nver touched language design (myself included).

Answer (score 0):

The existing answers explain the issue, but none show the correct way to get the correct size.

You would multiply the elements' `stride` (**not** their `size`! The stride is the `size`, rounded up to the nearest multiple of their `alignment`) by either the Array's `count` or `capacity`, depending on your use case.

```swift
let boolArray = Array(repeating: true, count: 10)

let totalBytes = boolArray.capacity * MemoryLayout<Bool>.stride
let usedBytes = boolArray.count * MemoryLayout<Bool>.stride

print("This array has a \(totalBytes) byte buffer, of which \(usedBytes) bytes are used.")
```