# Unable to send bytes to a an USB HID device in swift always get wrong report size

Tags: c, swift, macos, type-conversion

I'm porting an old C program to Swift on macOS. My problem is to send a fixed 7 bytes report to an USB HID device. In C this is working fine, but I haven't been able to make it work in Swift. What I have noticed that in C the size of the packet is correct, 7, in swift is always 1 byte more.

Here the original C code:

```c
int size;
char report[7] = {0x81, 0x61, 0xf5, 0x33, 0x04, 0x00, 0x28};
size = sizeof(report); // this returns 7
result = (*myhidInterface)->setReport(myhidInterface, kIOHIDReportTypeOutput, 0, report, sizeof(report), 1000, NULL, NULL, NULL); // IOReturn returns 0
```

This works and changing the value of the bytes, makes the device reacts fine.

In Swift I have tried different solutions but I'm not able to make it works, the size is always 8 bytes.

One was:

```swift
var report = [UInt8](repeating: 0, count: 7)
report = [0x81, 0x61, 0xf5, 0x33, 0x04, 0x00, 0x28] // the bytes are there if a print the report
let mySize = MemoryLayout.size(ofValue: report) // this return always 8 and not 7
result = myHIDDevInt!.setReport(hidDevInterface, kIOHIDReportTypeOutput, zero, &report, mySize, athousand, nil, nil, nil) // even in this case the return is 0, so no error
but it is not working.
```

I've tried also to get a pointer and the pass that to the setReport func of the device call with no luck:

```swift
MemoryLayout<UInt8>.alignment)
ptr.initializeMemory(as: UInt8.self, repeating: 0, count: 7)
```

then I do fill the bytes with:

```swift
ptr.storeBytes(of: 0x81, as: UInt8.self)
var offsetPointer = ptr + 1
offsetPointer.storeBytes(of: 0x61, as: UInt8.self)
offsetPointer = ptr + 2
offsetPointer.storeBytes(of: 0xf5, as: UInt8.self)
....
mySize =  UInt32(MemoryLayout.size(ofValue: ptr)) // even this reports 8 and not 7.
result = myHIDDevInt!.setReport(hidDevInterface, kIOHIDReportTypeOutput, zero, &report, mySize, athousand, nil, nil, nil)
```

The call to device reports even in this case no error.

I've tried to also write 7 in the device call but with no luck.

I would like to send a size of 7 as in C. I think in swift it changing the content of the report, better the order of the bytes.

I do also noticed that a binary operation such this below gives different result in C compare to swift:

```c
int arg; // size id 4 bytes
unsigned char theByte2; // size is 1 byte
arg = 1813;
theByte2 = (arg >> 8) & 0xff; // this return 0x61
```

while in Swift

```swift
var UInt8: theByte2 = 0 // size 1 byte
var arg: Int = 0 // size 4 bytes
arg = 1813
theByte2 = UInt8(((arg >> 8) & 0xff)) // this report 0x07
```

What I'm doing wrong here? There is a way to send 7 byte in swift and not 8?

Comment: Edit the question to provide a [mre]. The code shown does not behave the way you say it does. For example, `arg = 1813; theByte2 = (arg >> 8) & 0xff;` produces 0x7, not 0x61. There is some mistake in code you have not shown or that you have shown incorrectly.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Size of arrays in MemoryLayout.size in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60417000/size-of-arrays-in-memorylayout-size-in-swift)

Comment: Just a guess ... `sizeof` under C works, but swift appears to round up (it's more related to memory consumed than a "count"???). Try it _explicitly_: `let mySize = 7 var report = [UInt8](repeating: 0, count: mySize)
report = [0x81, 0x61, 0xf5, 0x33, 0x04, 0x00, 0x28] result = myHIDDevInt!.setReport(hidDevInterface, kIOHIDReportTypeOutput, zero, &report, mySize, athousand, nil, nil, nil)`

Comment: @CraigEstey It's not that. It's that OP is measuring the wrong thing. He's measuring of the `Array` struct itself (which is always 8 bytes on 64 bit platforms, regardless of the Array's `count`) instead of the size of _its buffer`. The linked question explains in more detail.

Comment: @Alexander OK thanks for point this out. Will try what you pointed out.

Comment: @Eric Postpischil: thank you, but no the code is that one: I need to send the HID device 7 bytes as report (some one are zeros, other are fixed values, the only compute is the second one) and the second must take a Int (signed 32 in a specific range) value and then apply to it the binary operation and then send the result in an (in swift) UIn8 byte.

Comment: @Eric Postpischil: In C that's ends up  in a Char and return 0X61. Do not why  in C the shift gives  you a different value compare to swift. Using C the passed byte make the device works. By the way looking deeply in the problem, I did  manually the binary operation and the correct answer should be the one in swift!!!Can be the char type in C acts different than the UInt8 in swift ore better the operating to convert from a type size 1 byte and a type sized 4 bytes.

Comment: @Alexander Thank you. Now I'm sure I'm sending the 7 bytes report and not the computed size. IE I manually put in the call to the device "7" as size. Still not working due to different binary operation result between C and Swift.

Comment: @Karterilla There's no need to hard code it, you just need to ask for the size of the right thing. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/78022404/3141234

Comment: @Karterilla Regarding your C code: "this return 0x61" no it doesn't, it's `0x07` in C, too. You've made a mistake elsewhere in your comparison.

Comment: @KarterillaIf If your question has been answered, you should mark one of the answers as accepted.

Answer (score 1):

You're calculating the size of your buffer incorrectly.

- `MemoryLayout.size(ofValue: report)` is calculating the size of the Array struct instance, which just wraps a pointer, and not the pointed-to buffer. It'll always be 64 bits on your 64-bit machine, regardless of the size of the pointed-to buffer.
- `MemoryLayout.size(ofValue: ptr)` is calculating the size of *the pointer itself*. Likewise, it'll also always be 64 bits.

You can use something like `report * MemoryLayout<UInt8>.stride`, but there's no need, because there are better APIs on `Array` which calculate this for you. Have a look at the ["Accessing Underling Storage" section of the Array docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array#accessing-underlying-storage).

I don't know the specifics of how [`IOHIDDevice.setReport`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/hiddriverkit/iohiddevice/3181240-setreport) imports into Swift, but using it should look something like this:

```swift
let report: [UInt8] = [0x81, 0x61, 0xf5, 0x33, 0x04, 0x00, 0x28]

report.withUnsafeBytes { buffer in
    myHIDDevInt!.setReport(
        hidDevInterface,
        kIOHIDReportTypeOutput,
        zero,
        buffer.baseAddress,
        buffer.count,
        athousand, nil, nil, nil
    )
}
```

Comment: Thank you everyone I made it working even without solving the different result between C and Swift.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you everyone I made it working even without solving the different result between C and Swift on the binary shift. Ie I do use the (correct) swift result. And not the C value I was aiming to. Do not why, but both are working in C and swift.

@Alexander I ended up, not hardcoding the size value, in something like this. Thanks for the .count hint, should have use it from the beginning.

```
var report = [UInt8](repeating: 0, count: 7)
var arg: Int = this is the Int with the value chosen by the user
theByte2 = UInt8((arg & 0xff))
report[firstByte, theByte2, thirdByte, fourthByte, fifthByte, sixthByte, seventhByte]
returnIOVal = myHIDDevInt!.setReport(hidDevInterface, kIOHIDReportTypeOutput, zero, &report, report.count, athousand, nil, nil, nil)
```

This made the device to work and change its behavior depending on the user input in the range values. Forget the madness of porting C triple stars swift conversion of IOKit calls... that did take me weeks to make it working.

I do add 2 screenshots of the binary shift (just that one no other operation on that var, but it is a size 4 to a size 1 Int to UInt implicit conversion beside the binary operation) in C and in swift by Xcode vars debug.

[image]

[image]

In C being a char it shows the ASCII value ie 0x61, 97 decimal

As usual thanx all and "stackoverflow" treasure chest.

Comment: You don't need to initialize `report` with `[UInt8](repeating: 0, count: 7)`, only to immediately discard that array and replace it with a new one. Just assign the literal to it once, like I showed.